# Shortcut for locking/unlocking specific object illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, shortcuts

I use command + 2 often to lock all and opt + command + 2 to unlock all. I was wondering if there is a shortcut to lock and unlock specific object you select?

Comment: That would be cmd+2

Answer (score 1):

> `"....unlock specific object you select"`

If an object is locked, you **can't** select it. That's sort of the point of locking.

Because you **can't** select a specific object, you can't unlock just a specific object, at least not via *shortcuts*.

It **is** possible to find a specific object in the **Layers Panel** and unlock the object there. Not sure about you, but how I work, often finding something minute and specific in the layers panel can take quite a while and a lot of trial and error by toggling visibility on and off to locate it.

Traditional workflow is to `Unlock All`, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, click the specific object you want unlocked, then `Lock` again.